# output HTML input range in range value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using `rangeslider.js` on a page and want to display the value in a hidden form field to be submitted. The hidden field can only accept a value in a range format, such as `50-205`, where `50` is the minimum of the range and `205` is the dynamic number that is selected from moving the slider around.

Currently, it seems that the value is being subtracted from the 50- I have in the code.  What do I need to do to make it so that the value is `50-xxx` where `xxx` is the dynamic value?

```
<input type="range" value="" min="50" max="800" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" data-rangeslider name='input_5' id='input_1_5' oninput="document.getElementById('testfield').value = 50-this.value)">

<input type="hidden" id="testfield" name="testfield" value="" />
```

Comment: well it is subtraction so if you want it to be the string, than use a string and do concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need some quotation marks, by the looks of it.

Using template strings:

```
oninput="document.getElementById('testfield').value = `50-${this.value}`"
```

Using `.toString()`

```
oninput="document.getElementById('testfield').value = '50-'+(this.value.toString())"
```

As pointed out by @Andreas, `HTMLInputElement#value` will always return a String, so you actually don't need the `.toString()` call here. If you want to use a Number data type at any point in the future, though, you would need to dive into [JavaScript type coercion](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/).

```
oninput="document.getElementById('testfield').value = '50-'+this.value"
```

Comment: The `.toString()` version is unnecessary complicated (`this.value` is already a string, and even if it wasn't a string, because `'50'` is also a string it would be automatically converted on concatenation) and doesn't yield the requested output.

Comment: As for the incorrect output, whoops-- forgot the hyphen. I've just fixed that. As for it being unnecessarily complicated, yes and no. I get that JS *would* implicitly take care of this, but because of the simplicity of the question and the likely low experience level the author has, I wanted to spell out the conversion instead of forcing them down the deep, dark hole of type coercion.

Comment: The `.value` property of an HTMLInputElement will always return a string, hence the `.toString()` call is unnecessary: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#htmlinputelement

Comment: Thank you both very much @IronFlare and Andreas, really appreciate the help and the information.  That did the trick!

Comment: Good catch @Andreas. I've edited my answer to include your information.